# global name 'constructor' is not defined

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a flask app and have a certain module inside called models.py with the following code:

```
import datetime, re

from app import db

def slugify(s):
    return re.sub('[^\w]+', '-', s).lower()

class Entry(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    slug = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    created_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    modified_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Entry, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # Call parent
        constructor.self.generate_slug()

    def generate_slug(self):
        self.slug = ''
        if self.title:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Entry: %s' % self.title
```

I also created a file called create_db.py with the following code:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
from main import db

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
```

From the ipython console I imported the Entry model using:

```
from models import *
```

However when I tried to run the commnad:

```
Entry = (title='A post about flask', body='This is the post body.')
```

I get the error:  `global name 'constructor' is not defined`

I need help figuring out the error. Thanks

Comment: What don't you understand about the error?

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is: there is nothing named `constructor` in your code. What do you think that line is supposed to be doing? Why are you using `constructor`? What do you think that's supposed to do?

Comment: In `Entry.__init__` you have `constructor.self.generate_slug()`.  That is a reference to `constructor`.  But you have not defined `constructor` anywhere.  So, either define `constructor` prior to referencing it, or else remove the reference to it.

Comment: What command did you try to run exactly? I.e did you mean to write `entry = Entry(title='A post about flask', body='This is the post body.')`?

Comment: yes pydsigner that was what I meant to write

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last line of your __init__ method or comment it out like so:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Entry, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # Call parent
    # constructor.self.generate_slug()
```

Since `constructor` is not defined anywhere, the interpreter cannot allow references to it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `constructor` is not defined. However, it looks like you just need to remove that name; if you change `constructor.self.generate_slug()` to `self.generate_slug()` your code should work correctly.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Entry, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # Call parent
    self.generate_slug()
```